# Linux read file permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Is there a Linux command, or a series of commands, which will allow me to get the permissions of a file in octal (e.g. 0644) format?

Comment: You might wanna ask Unix-related Questions on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try stat(1)

```
stat -c 0%a /etc/passwd
```

Comment: That's much more concise, +1.

Comment: To not include the leading zero: stat -c%a /etc/passwd

Answer (score 4):

From [unix.com: Display permissions in octal format](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/100630-display-permissions-octal-format.html):

```
perl -e 'printf "%o\n", (stat shift)[2] & 07777' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `fstat` on the file, look in the st_mode in the returned structure.

Answer (score 0):

The command is "stat" (Command line), and you can get at the info in code via fstat (See "man 2 stat")

Answer (score 0):

For OSX:

```
$ stat -f %p myfile
100644
```

or usually you're just interested in:

```
$ stat -f %Lp myfile
644
```